# Differential equation where there is an underlying distrubution in the coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation for the concentration of a chemical species $\theta$ numerically, where there is an underlying distribution in the value of a coefficient (as opposed to say a posterior distribution). The differential equation when there is no distribution would be

$$I(k_f, k_b)=\frac{d\theta}{dt}=k_{f}(1-\theta)-k_b \theta$$

whre $k_f$ and $k_b$ are rate constants. When there is a distribution for the probability of a molecule having a particular forwards and backwards rate constant, with a joint probability density function $\rho$ you get the expression

$$I_{dist}=\int_{k_f} \int_{k_b} \rho(k_f, k_b) I(k_f, k_b) dk_f\, dk_b$$.

So far, I've been approximating $I_{dist}$ using numerical quadrature

$$I_{dist} \approx \sum w(k_f, k_b) I(k_f, k_b)$$

where $w(k_f, k_b)$ is a weight calculated from joint pdf, but this requires repeated solving of the differential equation for different values of $k_f$ and $k_b$. Is there a better way to do this? Is it the same as a convolution?